# Partial derivative of mean of some variable

Tags: partial-derivative

I don't get the following

$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n x_i^2\right] = \frac{x}{2}
$$

Here x is a list of numbers (matrix or vector).

In my opinion it should be something like
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x_i} = \frac{2x_i}{n}
$$

Comment: Your last expression corresponds to $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x_\color{red}{i}} = \frac{2x_i}{n}$

Comment: Thanks for that, I just edited it.